Question regarding the Night Journey
In Sahih al-Bukhari 7517 Prophet Muhammad salallahu alayhi wasallam visited the 7 heavens with Prophets in each of them. But I am confused because I thought the samaa' ad dunya had stars and planets and stuff but it is said in the hadith that it contained rivers and a palace made of pearls and also emerald. Can someone explain this to me?
